# Make navigation menu slide in

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would I go about making this menu slide in on hamburger menu click? The background of it is an SVG and not an actual shape.

https://codepen.io/KirbStarRulz/pen/GdzOyM

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hamburger-container').on('click', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $('.hideMenu').toggleClass('slideInMenu');
    });
});

function myFunction(x) {
    x.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

Here's an image of what I need slid in (orange trapezoid on the right)
https://ibb.co/nRrr1T

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to slide in navigation. Your code works fine the only problem is negative z-index because of it your navigation is below all other elements.

```
.hideMenu {
    background-image: url(images/kreativez_menu_bg.svg);
    width: 48%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed;
    transform: translateX(200%);
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: transform 0.5s linear;
}
```

Comment: I didn't get it which html element you want to slide in? is it .hideMenu ul?